# build setup file for Windows application by including DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, deployment, installation

I have created windows application using windows c#.net and ms sql server 2008. And i am going to build setup file including database. Is that possible to build a setup including DB with out installing MS SQL Server 2008 in my client system?. If possible, this helps no need to install SQL server in my client system or else give a possible feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to load and use the database without a server running somewhere. Now, you could install that database on a remote server that is provided during installation - but a server has to be running somewhere.

Even loading it via **file** requires SQL Express to be running.

Comment: thank u for reply...
is their any alternate Data Base which can be build setup with Data Base?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert database to file (by detaching database) and then add that file to your project.